# aspose cells получить имена всех листов

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

кто нибудь работал с aspose cells?
Не могу понять как получить имена листов.
Хочу сделать так: посмотреть все имена листов, если совпадений не найдено, добавить лист с таким то именем. Ибо невозможно добавить 2 листа с одним именем. Но никак не могу допереть, как получить имена листов.

Comment: Просто добавлять лист и ловить исключение (try-catch)? Если исключения нет - лист добавился. Если есть - имя совпало.

Comment: точно, такой вариант подойдет, спасибо @AlexanderPetrov